# What additional documents should a South American going to the US bring to the border?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I'm going to the USA -alone- in March for a trip along the West Coast, from Los Angeles to Anchorage, Alaska. I already have all my hostels, flights and attractions booked and printed. I will also carry with me my visa (of course), return ticket and funds proof but I'm a little bit worried about what will happen to me on my arrival as I was told that the new administration doesn't really like people from South America. Since the latest events.

What other documents should I bring with me in order to prove to immigration officers that I'm not going to stay?

Comment: Despite what you hear, or fear, you have little or nothing to worry about. Landing in LA, many an immigration officer, and others of us in this country, will say bienvenido a los Estados Unidos de América y disfrutar de su visita (ou bem-vindo aos Estados Unidos da América e desfrutar da sua visita).

Comment: @pnuts I'm 25 and employed working in the IT field as an Engineer. I can print papers that evidence that I'm employed but I'm not sure if they will be valid in the US since they are written in Spanish. 
I can bring with me:
-My vacation approval email
-My bank account statement
-Paychecks
-Social security and individual tax identification papers

Comment: What is your citizenship? Unless you are from the República de Las Terroristas Islamofascistas del Mar Pirata y Socialista de Nueva Cuba Allah Akbar, this doesn't seem to be something that is targeted toward you.

Comment: @Robert Columbia  Rest assured that I'm not a citizen of the Islamic Republic of Las Terroristas Islamofascistas del Mar Pirata y Socialista de Nueva Cuba Allah Akbar :P
I'm an Argentine passport holder.

Comment: Oh, the translation of that joke is "The Republic of Islamofascist Terrorists of the Socialist Pirate Sea of New Cuba Allah is Great".

Comment: @NicoDSchwartzman given the huge number of Spanish speakers who enter through the southern US, you can be 100% certain that there will be Spanish speakers working at LAX immigration. I expect that a certain degree of proficiency is a job requirement.

Comment: @phoog "I expect that a certain degree of proficiency is a job requirement" It actually is with the CBP in general

Comment: @Crazydre What's your source for that? [This document](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/cbpo_reporting_duty_3.pdf) says that Spanish is required only in certain locations. I expect that in the on the northeast border, for example, French is more generally useful than Spanish.

Comment: @phoog https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1017/~/cbp-border-patrol-academy

Comment: @Crazydre the link is not working for me but I believe border patrol academy applies only to border patrol officers, who don't normally conduct immigration inspections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I am qualified to answer your questions because I am a well informed immigrant living in the USA. Yes you are being paranoid. First there is no evidence to show the new administration doesn't like South Americans. Even if you're from Mexico which clearly this administration has some issues with, Mexico is not a South American country. It is in north America.

You are 25,employed working in the IT field as an Engineer. You have hostels, flights and attractions booked and printed. You have evidence you are employed. Don't worry immigration will ALMOST DEFINITELY have someone who can read in Spanish. You have your vacation approval email, bank account statement,Paychecks, Social security and individual tax identification papers.

If I assume correctly the dates of your bookings correspond with your vacation letter. You were issued a visa, so prima facie I would say you have shown you are eligible to enter the USA and with the documents you have, barring doing and/or saying something outlandish to the immigration at the entry points, you should be able to enter without a hassle.

Make sure you have a multiple entry visa because you will be leaving the USA into Canada and then entering the USA again in Anchorage.

Enjoy your hike.

Comment: Argentinians get multiple entries by default